# Set input height equal to parent div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I set height of an input to be equal to its parent div, if the parent div has the height set to min-height: 10vh. *height: 100%* doesn't seem to work

```css
.item-card {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  /* border-top: 1px solid gray; */
  min-height: 10vh;
  text-align: start;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.items {
  padding: 0;
}

.items label {
  font-size: 1.8vw;
  color: black;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

input.task-input {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 1.8vw;
  padding: 0 0.6vw;
}
```

```html
<ul class="items">
  <li class="item-card">
    <i class="fa-regular fa-circle circle" onclick="markCompleted(event)"></i>
    <label class="task-label" ondblclick="changeTaskToInput(event)">Task 1</label>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark xmark" onClick="removeTask(event)"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="item-card">
    <i class="fa-regular fa-circle circle check-circle" onclick="markCompleted(event)"></i>
    <input type="text" class="task-input">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark xmark" onClick="removeTask(event)"></i>
  </li>
```

Comment: remove height:100% and align-items:center

Answer (score 1):

You can use `align-items: stretch` to make flex children fill up available space on the cross axis. You can also completely remove the `height` of the input in such case.

```css
.item-card {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  /* border-top: 1px solid gray; */
  min-height: 10vh;
  text-align: start;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.items {
  padding: 0;
}

.items label {
  font-size: 1.8vw;
  color: black;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

input.task-input {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  font-size: 1.8vw;
  padding: 0 0.6vw;
}
```

```html
<ul class="items">
  <li class="item-card">
    <i class="fa-regular fa-circle circle" onclick="markCompleted(event)"></i>
    <label class="task-label" ondblclick="changeTaskToInput(event)">Task 1</label>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark xmark" onClick="removeTask(event)"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="item-card">
    <i class="fa-regular fa-circle circle check-circle" onclick="markCompleted(event)"></i>
    <input type="text" class="task-input">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark xmark" onClick="removeTask(event)"></i>
  </li>
```